# Task scheduler for all users in C#

Tags: c#

I am using Task scheduler managed wrapper:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/TaskScheduler/

My requirement is to create a task for each user of the computer. How do I achieve it? Do I need to create only one task and set it to run for multiple users or I need to create copy of the task for each user of the machine. Currently I am reading all the users through directory service and creating task for each of those user by setting TaskDefinition's Prinicpal.UserId to that user name. It executes without any issues but I do not see any task created for the user. Basically my requirement is to create a task which will get executed on logon of any user. I know all the properties to setup for this but not know how to create it for all users so it gets executed.

Thanks
Jay

Comment: You could create a logon script for any local user account.

Comment: Thanks @sudheeshix I actually need to create Scheduled task as I use elevated tasks to launch an WPF application which requires admin privileges. The app need to get launched at startup.

Comment: Ok. What's the OS? In Windows 7, for instance, you can use Task Scheduler to create a task with a trigger of "at log on" for any user or a specific user.

You can probably script this using PowerShell too, if you dont want any manual steps to achieve this. Although I would like to write code for almost anything, IMHO, doing this in C# might not be the best approach.

Comment: OS is windows 8+. In my try last night, I got partial success. Yet to figure out the way for elevated launch.